# Websphere HibernatePersistence incompatible with PersistenceProvider

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, websphere

[Websphere v8.5.5 supports JPA 2.0](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/ae/rovr_specs.html) out of the box.

I am trying to deploy a WAR to a Websphere v8.5.5 application server. My persistence.xml specifies `org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence` as the JPA provider.

I have also set the JPA properties:

```
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.transaction.factory_class", "org.hibernate.transaction.CMTTransactionFactory");
jpaProperties.put("hibernate.transaction.manager_lookup_class", "org.hibernate.transaction.WebSphereExtendedJTATransactionLookup");
jpaProperties.put("jta.UserTransaction", "java:comp/UserTransaction");
```

as outlined [in this PDF presentation](https://www.google.com/search?q=AlternateJPAProviders_TestReport&rlz=1C1AFAB_enUS495US533&oq=AlternateJPAProviders_TestReport&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.369j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=Alternate+JPA+Providers+Test+Report&spell=1) and in [this IBM topic](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v8r5/topic/com.ibm.websphere.express.doc/ae/tejb_jpa3rdparty.html)

My application is set to "Parent Last" class loading policy and I have included in the WEB-INF/lib directory the following JARs:

- hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar
- hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar
- hibernate-core-4.2.5.Final.jar
- hibernate-entitymanager-4.2.5.Final.jar
- hibernate-envers-4.2.5.Final.jar

Despite all of this, I still get the following error on application startup:

```
[4/25/14 15:50:58:534 CDT] 0000007e JPAPUnitInfo  E   CWWJP0015E: An error occurred in the org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence persistence provider when it attempted to create the container entity manager factory for the fastPersistenceUnit persistence unit. The following error occurred: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence incompatible with javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceProvider
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.createEMFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1580)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPUnitInfo.createEntityManagerFactory(JPAPUnitInfo.java:1406)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAPxmlInfo.extractPersistenceUnits(JPAPxmlInfo.java:246)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAScopeInfo.processPersistenceUnit(JPAScopeInfo.java:119)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAApplInfo.processModulePUs(JPAApplInfo.java:167)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.AbstractJPAComponent.startingModule(AbstractJPAComponent.java:451)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.startingDeployedModule(JPAComponentImpl.java:729)
at com.ibm.ws.jpa.management.JPAComponentImpl.adjust(JPAComponentImpl.java:549)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.adjust(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1069)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectAdjust(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1394)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:627)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:774)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1374)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2179)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5474)
at com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5600)
at com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1266)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:69)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor44.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:272)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1148)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:298)
at com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
at sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1142)
at javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:995)
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:847)
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:783)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
at com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
at com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
at com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
at com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:175)
at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1862)
```

Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of this error?

Comment: Related but does not answer my question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2775069/953327

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar.

My understanding of the linked articles was that I should be including this JAR with my application. However, by removing this JAR the class cast exception has gone away.

Answer (score 0):

The only option (aside from not overriding javax.persistence) is to disable container-managed JPA altogether for this application.  See the documentation in [PM26361](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM26361).